# Magento2 add js files via requirejs

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery

Been trying to figure out how to add some custom JS files with requirejs.

I've been successful in adding them via default_head_blocks.xml, however... in doing so... they get loaded before the jquery script that magento2 uses...

so I am wondering how I can use the requirejs to add a few .js files and make sure they are loaded AFTER the jquery library?

I read the documentation here:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js-resources.html

but it's talking about modules and such, I don't have a module, I am just trying to add some jquery scripts on product pages and the home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use that  in you js file all code inside that. this will load the jquery first. after that just add you script via `default_head_blocks.xml` that worked for and hope worked for you.

```
require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ //your js file code here  });
```

**this solution for theme**

Comment: That looks really promising, I can see what its doing by the require... but I added that to the page, and have the js loaded in the     default_head_blocks.xml - it didn't work.

Comment: `require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ $(window).load(function() {
  $("#container1").twentytwenty();
});});` add it like that for unction

Comment: does that snippet have any dependencies? do I still need to have a module made, or use the require js somehow? - I put that snippet in the product details of the item that needs this script... and it still does not work.

Comment: if you load the js that are using the $ or jquery you need to add that in between `require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ });` add between these `{}` to make it work

Comment: I tried it like: `require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ $(window).load(function() { $(".twentytwenty-container").twentytwenty(); });});`

Comment: the file include also need as a same.

Comment: got it figured out based on your help! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From theme you can configuration require like in location `app\design\frontend\[Vendor]\[theme]\[Vendor_Module]\web`

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        //your require js lib here
        "jquery_2": "Magento_Theme/js/jquery/jquery2.min",
        "jcarousel": "Magento_Theme/js/jcarousel/jquery.jcarousel"
    }
},
shim: {
    //dependency third-party lib
    "jcarousel": {
        deps: [
            'jquery_2' //dependency jquery will load first
        ]
    }
},
paths: {

}

};
```

Do same way for module in location `app\code\[Vendor]\[Module]\view\[area]`

Comment: thanks for the reply, that's my question though, you say "Module" - I dont have a module?